# COM-class without being able to instantiate

Tags: com

MSDN:

"You implement an IClassFactory interface for each (COM) class of object that you offer to be instantiated."

Is it useful to create COM class without Class Factory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IClassFactory is provided for objects which are instantiated ***directly*** by the caller, for example using `CreateObject` or `CoCreateInstance`, or `GetObject`.

Other objects can be obtained by getting them indirectly from objects that are created.

For example, the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` in VB or VBScript is created directly. You can use the methods to obtain `File` or `Folder` objects, which cannot be directly created. Instead these are created by the FileSystemObject and returned from FileSystemObject methods.

Comment: So, there is some kind of hierarchy of COM-object. it's like "inheriting" in terms of OOP. Good example!

Comment: @UnhandledException, not really like inheriting. The object you create can act as a factory for other objects, or they can be returned from functions. The purpose of IClassFactory is to act as a ***standard*** factory for objects you create ***directly***. It's a convenience - essentially its "the thing you do if you want CreateObject/CoCreateInstance to work".

Answer (score 1):

> Is it useful to create COM class without Class Factory?

Yes, why not? It can still be fully featured COM class, just except that you cannot launch it via `CoCreateInstance` API. For some reason you might want to make it available otherwise, e.g. as a returned [out] parameter on a method of another interface/class, or via `GetActiveObject` API.

Class factories let you expose your class for direct instantiation.

Comment: I don't know. Why not or why yes. This is a question. This doesn't tell you that I complain about something or not. I'm going deep and want to learn facts. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: If you're building everything from the ground and you don't need a class factory, then you might want to skip it. Standard frameworks and libraries typically provide you with default class factory implementation and it's cheap and easy to use it on your class, you might need a specific rare reason to reject default standard class factory provided to you.

Comment: ok, as I understood, there is some rare benefit of custom factoring.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure the wording is quite correct here.  You almost always implement [IClassFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) *once* for *all* COM classes of objects that your host will instantiate.  In particular, your implementation of IClassFactory is what gets returned from [DllGetClassObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In particular, when someone calls `CoCreateInstance(CLSID_foo, pUnkOuter, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IFoo, (void **) &pFoo)`, the following things happen (assuming you're not doing remoting):

1. COM looks up `CLSID_foo` in the registry.  (In particular, HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\\InprocServer32).
2. COM loads that DLL and calls [DllGetClassObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with IID_IClassFactory.
3. Your DLL returns a function pointer to the implementation of [IClassFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
4. COM calls your implementation of [IClassFactory::CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `pUnkOuter`, `IID_IFoo`, and `pFoo`.

There are many other situations where you would have COM objects that aren't directly creatable, as @Ben mentioned.  There are even other standard factory interfaces, like [IServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678965%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that exist so that classes can expose a dynamic set of interfaces.